# I require two comparisons to be true for an if statement but pandas gives an error. How can I rewrite the statement in a way pandas will accept?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The if statement is as follows:

```
for line in result
    if result < 0 and test == 1:
        test = 0
        print('patient result ', (TestAmount/SMAs.amount[line] - 1))
```

There are a sequence of these but the issue is in the if statement. When I run the code I get an error saying 
`"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."`

I understand that this means that I cannot have the if statement criteria as I have them with pandas but do not know how to correct it. Is it possible to condition an if statement on two things when using a pandas DataFrame?

I am very new to coding and am very unfamiliar with terminology. I am hoping to write a program to analyse lab data once and then hopefully not have to do too much more with it.

Comment: are `result` and `test` columns in your dataframe?

Comment: result is a list of measurements that come as floats and test is a variable set to 1 when we have administered  treatment. Thank you for any help!

Comment: EDIT: If it helps, result = SMAs.result. where SMAs is a csv of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of booleans use bitwise operations instead of `and` and `or`:

```
(result < 0) & (test == 1)
```

If you want all items to be `True` use `all`:

```
(result < 0).all() and (test == 1)
```

Or if you want just to run the condition on each value use the variable from the `for`:

```
(line < 0) and (test == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped to fix this. It turns out the problem was that line was not an integer. this was fixed by replacing the for loop as follows:

```
for line in range(0,len(SMAs)):
```

Thank you for all help.